# Firebase 3 can't modify other user created data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In this application, each user has a counter for "votes" but it only works when the same user votes, when another user tries to do a FIRTransaction in that reference it returns nil. The rules are set to any user.
When I need that user2 updates the user1 "votes" value it doesn't reads that key value to perform the transaction block, so it returns nil.

```
votesCountRef = ref.child("user1").child("votes")
votesCountRef.runTransactionBlock( { (currentData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
            let value = currentData.value! as! Int
            currentData.value = value + 1
            return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
        })
```

result:

> Received votes actual value: Optional()
>   Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x110684600) to 'NSNumber' (0x10fce92a0).

But when original user runs this it works successfully.

Json tree for user1:

```
{ 
  "userUID" : "user1",
  "votes" : 2
}
```

Database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Thanks to @Frank I could manage it like this:

```
    ownerReceivedVotesCountRef.runTransactionBlock( { (currentData) -> FIRTransactionResult in

    let value = currentData.value as? Int ?? 0
    currentData.value! = (value as Int) + 1
    return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction handler is initially run with the client's best guess fo rthe current value. Quite often that will be `nil`, so your code has to handle that.

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#save_data_as_transactions):

> Note: Because `runTransactionBlock:andCompletionBlock:` is called multiple times, it must be able to handle `nil` data. Even if there is existing data in your remote database, it may not be locally cached when the transaction function is run, resulting in `nil` for the initial value.

Something like this should work for your case:

```
let value = currentData.value as? Int ?? 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to put the formatted code for the solution:            `ownerReceivedVotesCountRef.runTransactionBlock( { (currentData) -> FIRTransactionResult in  
            print("\(self.currentPost!.owner) Received votes actual value: \(currentData.value)")  
            let value = currentData.value as? Int ?? 0  
            currentData.value! = (value as Int) + 1  
            return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)  
        })`